# How to find and identify keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: edit-mode, video, shortcut

What is the best way to more easily identify keyboard shortcuts, specifically for the video editing capabilities?

For example, a set of keyboard stickers.

Comment: Welcome to the site :) I've rephrased your question slightly so it's more on-topic. If you disagree with any of my edits, feel free to [roll them back or add more edits of your own](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing).
That said, you might find [this](http://waldobronchart.github.io/ShortcutMapper/#Blender) useful (all the OS's except for OSX seem broken atm, but the OSX shortcuts are all pretty much the same so perhaps it's still helpful regardless of what OS you use).

Comment: The User Preferences has a tab for shortcuts in which you can search for either a combination of keys or the name of the operator as well as filter by category (as in which editor or context it is available).

Comment: There is a [guide](http://giudansky.com/design/51-blender-map)

Answer (score 1):

In *User Preferences*, (menu entry *Edit> Preferences> Keymap*) you'll see an exhaustive list of the currently set keyboard shortcuts.

There is also a handy search bar in there to search through them. You can search by name (default) or change it to search by key binding by clicking on the little dropdown to the left of the search bar.

You can find more info about it at the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html).